# Como hacer rutas en laravel 8 con apiResources

Tags: php, laravel

Tengo unas rutas del Api que estoy tratando de implemantar con laravel 8, que son de tipo apiResources.
Actualmente la rutas la tengo implementada de la siguiente forma

```
Route::apiResources([
    'users' => [UserController::class],
    'post' => [PostController::class],
]);
```

Pero me aparace el siguiente error cuando llamo a la ruta.

```
ErrorException: Array to string conversion in file
 C:\Users\USUARIO\Documents\Proyectos\api\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\ResourceRegistrar.php on line 410
```

Este error no es en ningun metodo solo En cambio con una ruta de tipo **apiResource** individual no me aparece este error por ejemplo esta ruta.

```
Route::apiResource('users', BarriosController::class);
```

Como puedo implementar **apiResources** con el nuevo sistema de routing de laravel?

Comment: Has intentado sin corchetes `Route::apiResources(['users' => UserController::class,'post' => PostController::class,]);`

Comment: @FelipeUrcia si esto funciona

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución fue quitarle los [] despues de => resultando de esta forma

```
Route::apiResources([
    'users' => UserController::class,
    'post' => PostController::class,
]);
```